# SignalR bot only checks for exact case message.Contains. What about misspellings?

Tags: c#, bots

I have a bot that will respond to certain trigger words

```
 if (message.Contains("trigger"))
            {
                HandleTrigger(message);
                return ;
            }
```

How can I foolproof this concept with a way to allow misspellings like 'triger' or 'triggr' So that it will still hit this breakpoint and return `HandleTrigger(message);`

More code for context:

```
void HandleTrigger(string message)
        {
            if (message.Contains("trigger2"))
            {
                ReplyMessage(viewTriggerMessage);
                ReplyMessage(repeatMessage);
                return;
            }
            if (message.Contains("trigger3"))
            {
                ReplyMessage(anotherMyTriggerMessage);
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use Soundex algorithm code to generate a simple output that can be categorized correctly.

This is mostly used in an SQL database for finding strings that are similarly spelled.

`Console.WriteLine(Soundex.For("Trigger"));` //outputs 'T626'
`Console.WriteLine(Soundex.For("Triggr"));`  //outputs 'T626'

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6OhjLT

Comment: Soundex as compared to Metaphone has drawbacks. An interesting read http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1848528

Answer (score 5):

Your question does not seem to be a SignalR question. It is more about matching misspelled words. There is an algorithm called the Double Metaphone that you can use to match misspelled words. It works on the principles of a phonetic match. You can read more on the algorithm here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone#Double_Metaphone

You can find a C# implementation on this link. https://code.google.com/p/doublemetaphone/

Once you add the class from the above link to your project, you get an extension method to String variables called GenerateDoubleMetaphone()

And then you can compare the metaphones to check for similarity. In your example, you can write your if condition like this

```
if ("trigger".GenerateDoubleMetaphone().Equals(message.GenerateDoubleMetaphone()))
{
//Execute code for a match
}
```

In the example above the metaphones for "trigger" and "trigr" are both "TRKR" and hence will match.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! I only referenced the fact I'm using signalR because the bot is located under a SignalR Hub class. I was looking at using Soundex but the algorithm doesn't really work for typos without me tweaking the rules a bit.

Comment: @majache you are correct about the matches returned with Soundex as compared to Metaphones. Metaphones have a higher match percentage. I have added an article for reference.